# How to click on button in application pop up window in protractor?

Tags: protractor

Pop up window "No" button html code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
```

Pop up window "Yes" button html code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="sendBulkMail()">Yes</button>
```

Complete code:

```
<div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body container-fluid mainformFieldsWrap">
                Are you sure you want to send bulk interest mail to candidates?
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="sendBulkMail()">Yes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Problem : In our application, am clicking on "delete button", after clicking on delete button am getting pop up window and in that pop up window i have to click on 'Yes'or 'No' button.

How to do it?

Comment: is your pop-up a type of alert or prompt? Can you paste the complete code of it? If its an alert, then you can use the protractor's inbuilt `alert()` function. Thanks

Comment: @GirishSortur We are using it as Prompt. Can u please help me. i pasted complete code.

Comment: `browser.driver.switchTo().activeElement()` will switch the focus to Prompt. Then you can click on Yes button.

Comment: @GirishSortur We are using as a Prompt. I pasted all code please have a look...

Comment: @PriyanshuShekhar    browser.driver.switchTo().activeElement();
        browser.sleep(5000);
        element(by.partialButtonText("Close")).click();    I tried like this but it is giving error "element not visible".

Comment: As per your code it looks you are looking for `Close` button instead of `No`. Recheck it.

Comment: @raghavendrat have you tried to click on the element without switching or using anything else? By your html code it seems that you are using a modal and not an html prompt element. Just click on the no button - `$('button[data-dismiss="modal"]').click()`. Similarly try on clicking other elements as you need. If you are getting any error, do let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve any service call or any function after click event, we can use something like this:

```
   browser.driver.switchTo().activeElement(); 
   browser.sleep(5000); 
   element(by.buttonText("Yes")).click();
   browser.sleep(5000);
```

or

```
    element(by.css(".modal-content")).element(by.buttonText("Yes")).click();
    browser.sleep(5000);
```

or

```
   var DeclineBtn = element(by.buttonText('Yes'));    browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click()",DeclineBtn.getWebElement());
        browser.sleep(5000);
```

basically, browser.sleep(5000) will let your function to execute